# Creating a conditional section in a react custom component

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a custom component that renders a container box. The component initially looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-flexbox-grid';

const Box = (props) => (
    <div className="box">
        <Row between="xs" className="box-top">
            <span className="box-title">{props.title}</span>
        </Row>
        <Col xs={12} className="box-info">
            {props.content}
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} className="box-bottom">
        </Col>
    </div>
);

export default Box;
```

It displays a div with class box that contains the CSS to generate the look and feel. The inner divs with the exception of box-info are conditional. Sometimes this component will be used with a box-title and sometimes it's not. Same happens with the box-bottom.

When I use it, I would like to use something like this:

```
<Box
    showTitle
    title={'Title'}
    content={'My content is here'}
/>
```

and sometimes like this:

```
<Box
    showTitle={false}
    showBottom={false}
    content={'My content is here'}
/>
```

How do I set up the props to allow for the box-title and box-bottom to hide if I use showTitle = false or showBottom = false?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `showTitle={false}` by simply omitting it. :~)

There are a few ways to do [conditional rendering in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html). One approach is

```
{props.showTitle &&
  <Row between="xs" className="box-top">
    <span className="box-title">{props.title}</span>
  </Row>
}
```

If `props.showTitle` exists, it will render whatever is after the logical `&&` operator.

You can also use the ternary operator if you want to render something in case the condition is not met, like so

```
{props.showTitle ? (
  <Row between="xs" className="box-top">
    <span className="box-title">{props.title}</span>
  </Row>
) : (
  <SomeOtherComponent />
)}
```

As a side-note, you can look into [`prop-types`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to check for the type of `props` that your components receive.

Comment: That was awesome. Thank you!

Comment: I realized you took away the `this.` I figured that out when I was using your code. But thank you for making the changes here as well

Comment: Yep, I noticed you had a stateless component but forgot to take off the `this` the first time I made my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third option, which consists in using a [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) inside the JSX syntax:

```
{(() => {
  if (isSomethingTrue === true) {
     return <MyComponent />
  } else {
     return 'Whoops!'
  }    
})()}
```